# Sharing files from Ubuntu 19.04 to Windows - can't find Samba

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, samba

I am trying to share a folder on my Ubuntu 19.04 virtual machine (VirtualBox) with a Windows 10 host. All of the tutorials I find are pretty similar and start by asking me to run the following command to install Samba:

```
sudo apt-get install samba smbfs
```

However, Ubuntu complains that the `smbfs` package is unavailable and the file `/etc/samba/smb.conf` does not exist.

How do I accomplish this without this package?

Comment: Your post is a bit vague, so when are you told that the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file doesn't exist (after an install), and what version of Ubuntu are we talking here?

Answer (score 1):

I never realized this until your question but apt / apt-get will not install any package on a list of packages if one of those packages does not exist.

This is the case with smbfs which was removed from the repository years ( 7? ) ago. You are looking at a very old howto.

Install samba by itself:

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

And please follow George Udosen's advice and tell people what version of Ubuntu you are using and in this case what version of Windows you are using when asking a Samba question. Win10 for example can do things prior Windows cannot.

Comment: Ok I have added the version number to my post. I'm going to look at the Samba documentation, see how I create a link.